# Function for loops with a different process within the loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I've got a very similar process that occurs in many places, with one small change. I was wondering what would be the best way to make the code neater. Currently, the process is:

```
var drawx = 0;
    var drawy = 0;
    while(drawy < 22){
        while(drawx < 10){
            if(nextBlock[drawx][drawy] != false){
                base[drawx][drawy] = nextBlock[drawx][drawy];
            }
            drawx++;
        }
        drawx = 0;
        drawy++;
    }
```

Within the while drawx < 10 is where I usually have different things to run, and I'm not sure how I would create a function with a variable process in the middle of it. Is there a way to do this, or should I just create a function that does this process and executes a certain if statement depending on the parameter that was called when running the function?

EDIT: I think I might have not gotten my initial problem across. I want to be able to have a process such as the if statement within the loop to be a variable process while the rest of it to be the same

Comment: Well, the really low-hanging fruit is to use for loops instead of whiles.

Comment: you should create function seperately and call it from your drawx < 10 loop

Comment: I think my answer addresses your question, as edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript has first class functions so you can do something like this:

```
function drawLoop(action) {
    var drawx = 0;
    var drawy = 0;
    while(drawy < 22){
        while(drawx < 10){
            action(drawx, drawy);
            drawx++;
        }
        drawx = 0;
        drawy++;
    }
 }
```

And then call it like this:

```
drawLoop(function(drawx, drawy){
        if(nextBlock[drawx][drawy] != false){
            base[drawx][drawy] = nextBlock[drawx][drawy];
        }
});
```

And of course, you can change the function you pass to drawLoop to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you could inject a function as a variable to your generic function like

```
function genericDraw(xValidation) {
var drawx = 0;
var drawy = 0;
while(drawy < 22){
    while(xValidation(drawX)){
        if(nextBlock[drawx][drawy] != false){
            base[drawx][drawy] = nextBlock[drawx][drawy];
        }
        drawx++;
    }
    drawx = 0;
    drawy++;
}
}
```

where xValidation is

```
function someValidation(value) {
return (value < 10);
}
```

and you call it

```
genericDraw(someValidation);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( var drawy = 0 ; drawy < 22 ; drawy++) {
    for( var drawx = 0 ; drawx < 10 ; drawx ++) {
        if(nextBlock[drawx][drawy] != false) {
            base[drawx][drawy] = nextBlock[drawx][drawy];            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why you think this solution will work.